# Checking a line through a 2D array

Tags: multidimensional-array

I have a 2D `boolean` array (a `boolean[][]`), and I have two points (`(x, y)`). I want to draw a line between these two points and see if the line intersects any space that has a `true` value.

For clarification, imagine each element is `1 unit x 1 unit`. The `boolean[][]` will always be rectangular. I am raycasting from the centres of the specified points.

I don't really know where to start, some advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to be clear, the line you are drawing is within the same coordinate space as your 1 bit grid, correct?  So it's simply a function of finding the cells that represent the line.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch Yes. I have a feeling this is really simple, but I can't think of how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, it sounds like you simply want to calculate which binary points in your grid are affected by the line.  For the longest time, computers have used [Bresenham's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm).  It's been adapted in later years to use anti-aliasing.  Since you are dealing with simple on/off bits you can use the simple algorithm.  The link has much more of the theory, and some adaptations of the algorithm for other line problems.

The pseudo code will look like something like this:

```
deltaX = p1.X - p0.X
deltaY = p1.Y - p0.Y
error = -1.0

# NOTE: assuming deltaX is not 0 (vertical)
slope = Abs(deltaY / deltaX)
y = p0.Y

for(x = p0.X; x < p1.X; x++)
{
    check(x,y) # plot/check, this is the point of interest

    error += slope
    if(error >= 0.0)
    {
        y += 1
        error -= 1
    }
}
```

A couple notes:

- Everything that is not a coordinate need to be floating point numbers (including deltaX and deltaY)
- `p0` and `p1` are points (x,y) and can be integers

Comment: So just to clarify, `check(x, y)` is where I do something with every point on the line, am I correct?

Comment: I'm guessing so, because this solution works. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexL. Sorry, I had a busy weekend (I'm a new grandpa).  Yes.  From the original algorithm the name of the function was `plot(x,y)`.  And no problem.